# Set of integers not divisible by smaller set of primes

Tags: functions, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the sequence of prime numbers, and $s(x,n)=$ the set of integers less or equal than $x$ that are *not* divisible by $p_1,\dots,p_n.$ I can define it as follows:

```
s[x_,n_]:=DeleteCases[Map[If[Total[Table[Map[If[CoprimeQ[Prime[Range[n]],a][[#]]==True,1,0]&,Range[n]],{a,1,x}],{2}][[#]]==n,Range[x][[#]],0]&,Range[x]],0]
```

But it is inefficient. I am sure there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this is correct, and very fast:

```
fn[x_Integer, n_Integer] :=
  Complement[Range @ x, Join @@ Range[#, x, #]] & @ Prime @ Range @ n
```

Test:

```
fn[10000, 1223]
```

> ```
> {1, 9929, 9931, 9941, 9949, 9967, 9973}
> ```

---

It seems I am a bit late to return to this problem and Simon Woods already provided a memory optimized approach.  His sieve is comparatively fast when the return list is long, that is to say when `n` is small relative to `x`, but there is a much more efficient approach when the return list is short, that is when `n` is large.

The core of my method is this:

```
fx[x_Integer, n_Integer] /; x < Prime[n + 1]^2 := Prime@Range[n + 1, PrimePi@x] ~Prepend~ 1
```

Note the condition; this method is not valid for small `n` values, but that is exactly where Simon's code is superior anyway.  However as `n` increases this method becomes faster, ultimately being instantaneous when the output is `{1}` which is where Simon's code is slowest:

```
tbl = Table[f[1*^7, n] // Length // Timing, {n, 5*^4, 7*^5, 5*^4}, {f, {fn2, fx}}];

ListPlot[tbl\[Transpose], PlotLegends -> {"SparseArray", "Prime"}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Seconds", "Output Length"}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Clearly these are complementary methods!  Therefore I propose this:

```
fnHybrid[x_Integer, n_Integer] :=
  With[{pp = PrimePi @ x},
    If[pp - n < 2 n,
      Prime @ Range[n + 1, pp] ~Prepend~ 1,
      Module[{y = Range @ x},
        (y[[# ;; x ;; #]] = 0) & /@ Prime @ Range @ Min[n, pp];
        SparseArray[y]["NonzeroValues"]]]]
```

The crossover point may need to be tuned for other `x` values but this is surely the best of both worlds:

[image]

Comment: Yes, very, very fast!! :)

Comment: @martin Thanks for the Accept.  I usually recommend waiting 24 hours first, to let everyone around the world have a chance to answer.  However in this case I doubt there is a generally faster method available as this already makes use of highly optimized operations.  Compilation to C could be faster still of course, but I don't do that. ;^)

Comment: I would usually wait, but I couldn't see anything being much faster, as you say!!

Comment: @martin Although I haven't found anything *faster* than the code above there are memory optimization to be made especially when `n` is large relative to `x`, e.g. in the case where the result is `{1}`.  I'll add these later today if I have time.

Answer (score 16):

This is competitive with Mr Wizards code and seems faster in some cases:

```
fn2[x_Integer, n_Integer] := Module[{y = Range @ x},
  (y[[# ;; x ;; #]] = 0) & /@ Prime[Range @ Min[n, PrimePi @ x]];
  SparseArray[y]["NonzeroValues"]]

AbsoluteTiming[fn[10000, 1223];]
(* {0.004000, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[fn2[10000, 1223];]
(* {0.010001, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[fn[2000000, 100000];]
(* {0.828047, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[fn2[2000000, 100000];]
(* {0.412023, Null} *)
```

Comment: +1. It becomes about twice as fast as the list grows!

Comment: This is related to the memory optimization I had in mind but you executed it better than I would have. (And `Min[n, PrimePi @ x]` didn't occur to me.) :-)  I found a method complementary to this; see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
ss[x_, n_] :=  Flatten@Position[CoprimeQ[#, Sequence @@ Prime[Range@n]] & /@ Range@x, True]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use a simple sieve to find these numbers in $O(x \log \log x)$ time. I went ahead and compiled my solution to make it as fast as possible.

```
PrimesUpTo = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Block[{S = Range[2, n]},
    Do[
      If[S[[i]] != 0,
        S[[2i+1 ;; -1 ;; i+1]] *= 0;
      ],
      {i, Sqrt[n]}
    ];
    Select[S, Positive]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
];

F = Compile[{{x, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
  Block[{S = Range[x], primes = PrimesUpTo[Prime[1223]]},
    Do[
      If[S[[p]] != 0,
        S[[p ;; -1 ;; p]] *= 0;
      ],
      {p, primes}
    ];
    Select[S, Positive]
  ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed",
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
];
```

Here's timings of all functions so far:

```
F[10000, 1223] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.001991, {1, 9929, 9931, 9941, 9949, 9967, 9973}} *)

fn[10000, 1223] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.007860, {1, 9929, 9931, 9941, 9949, 9967, 9973}} *)

fn2[10000, 1223] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.004625, {1, 9929, 9931, 9941, 9949, 9967, 9973}} *)
```

### Edit

I just realized Simon Wood's method is the same as mine, but he uses sparse arrays.

Comment: What is `fastCompile`?

Comment: I think there must be an n/logn factor to account for the number of primes in the sieving process.

Comment: Sure, you're right. I guess I was considering `n` to be constant.

Comment: @RunnyKine, whoops I copy and pasted `PrimesUpTo` from my init file and that's where `fastCompile` is defined. I'll change it.