# Finding large prime gaps

Tags: function-construction, prime-numbers

I am using basic searches for prime gaps as follows:

```
greater[list_] := First@# & /@ Split[list, Greater]
primeG[nn_] := With[{aa = Prime@Range@PrimePi@(nn)}, 
 With[{bb = (Rest@aa - Most@aa)}, 
  With[{cc = (First@# & /@ Split@Nest[greater, bb, Round@(Log@nn^2)])}, 
   With[{dd = Prime@First@Flatten@# & /@ (Position[bb, #] & /@ cc)},
Transpose@{cc - 1, dd}]]]]

primeGmax[r1_, r2_] := 
With[{bb = Split@PrimeQ@Range[If[EvenQ@r1 == True, r1 + 1, r1], r2, 2]}, 
 With[{aa = Length@# & /@ bb}, With[{dd = Max@aa}, 
   With[{cc = Position[aa, dd][[1, 1]]}, 
2 {dd + 1/2, Length@Flatten@Take[bb, cc] - dd + If[EvenQ@r1 == True, r1 + 1, r1]/2 - 1}]]]]

primeG[10^3]
primeGmax[10^2, 10^3]

(*
{{0, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 7}, {5, 23}, {7, 89}, {13, 113}, {17, 523}, {19, 887}}
{19, 887}
*)
```

This also appears to work for larger numbers:

```
With[{pp = 1425172824437000000}, primeGmax[pp, pp + 10^6]]
(*{1475, 1425172824437699411}*)
```

The *Mathematica* code on these OEIS sequences ([A008996](https://oeis.org/A008996), [A002386](https://oeis.org/A002386)) seems to be no more efficient.

Is there a cleverer way, using `Mod`  small primes other than 2? I know there are programs written especially for this purpose - is it better to use those for large nujmbers, or is *Mathematica* a viable platform for these kind of searches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I rewrote your `primeG`, ignorant of clever methods. Nevertheless, with `[[All,1]]` and the fourth argument to `Position` you can get a 50% speed increase. Also, since you already calculate the primes in `aa`, there is no need to use `Prime` in calculating `dd`.

```
MartinPrimeGaps[nn_]:=
   With[{aa = Prime@Range@PrimePi@nn}, 
      With[{bb = Differences[aa]}, 
         With[{cc = Split[Nest[Split[#, Greater][[All, 1]] &, bb, 
                               Round@(Log@nn^2)]][[All, 1]]},
            Transpose[{cc - 1, 
                       aa[[Flatten[Position[bb, #, 1, 1] & /@ cc]]]}]]]]
```

**Update**
I rewrote `primeGmax` in two different ways. The first `MaxPrimeGap1` uses a lot of memory when a large range is required, and is cleaner but not significantly faster than `primeGmax`.

```
MaxPrimeGap1[r1_?OddQ, r2_] :=
   Block[{p = Range[r1, r2, 2], gaps, maxgap},
      gaps = Differences[p = Pick[p, PrimeQ[p]]] - 1;
      maxgap = Max[gaps];
      {maxgap, p[[Position[gaps, maxgap, 1, 1][[1, 1]]]]}]
```

The second `MaxPrimeGap2` uses almost no memory, but `NextPrime` makes it significantly slower than `MaxPrimeGap1`.

```
MaxPrimeGap2[r1_?OddQ, r2_] :=
   Block[{p1 = r1, p2 = NextPrime[r1], g, b = {0, 0}},
      g = {p2 - p1 - 1, p1};
      While[p1 < r2,
         p2 = NextPrime[p1];
         g = {p2 - p1 - 1, p1};
         p1 = p2;
         If[g[[1]] > b[[1]], b = g]
      ];
      b]
```

The slow part of the code is testing for primality. Specifying only odd numbers in the `Range` statement cuts the number of tests in half. Sieve methods, which continue cutting numbers in the range, are very fast. I rewrote code from @SimonWoods [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58520/set-of-integers-not-divisible-by-smaller-set-of-primes) to return a list of candidate numbers between `nmin` and `nmax` not divisible by the first `m` primes.

```
CandidatePrimes[nmin_Integer, nmax_Integer, m_Integer] :=
   Module[{y = Range[nmin, nmax], min, max = nmax - nmin + 1},
      Map[If[(min = # - Mod[nmin, #] + 1) <= max, (y[[min ;; max ;; #]] = 0)] &,
          Prime[Range[m]]];
      SparseArray[y]["NonzeroValues"]]
```

Now use `CandidatePrimes` to reduce the number of prime checks.

```
MaxPrimeGap3[r1_?OddQ, r2_Integer, m_Integer] :=
   Block[{p = CandidatePrimes[r1, r2, m], gaps, maxgap},
      gaps = Differences[p = Pick[p, PrimeQ[p]]] - 1;
      maxgap = Max[gaps];
      {maxgap, p[[Position[gaps, maxgap, 1, 1][[1, 1]]]]}]
```

If you have parallel processors, then it is faster to use `Pick[p,ParallelMap[PrimeQ,p]]` instead of `Pick[p,PrimeQ[p]`. Call this version `MaxPrimeGap4`.

Set the lower limit to a large prime, `NextPrime[10^12]`.

```
AbsoluteTiming[MaxPrimeGap1[1000000000039, 1000000000039 + 10^7]]
(* {16.682, {321, 1000008002317}} *)

AbsoluteTiming[MaxPrimeGap3[1000000000039, 1000000000039 + 10^7, 300]]
(* {13.427, {321, 1000008002317}} *)
```

Using 8 parallel kernels, `MaxPrimeGap4` takes 3.9 s. Another example:

```
AbsoluteTiming[MaxPrimeGap4[1000000000000037, 1000000000000037 + 10^8, 1000]]
(* {36.631, {489, 1000000025764111}} *)
```

Comment: great - thanks :) I am really most interested in extending the range for `primeGmax` ($10^7$ is a drop in the ocean at that height) - any ideas?

Comment: No ideas yet, looking through my books... Have you seen papers by Bertil Nyman and Thomas Nicely? and references therein?

Comment: have been browsing Thomas Nicely's website, but unfortunately I am rather ignorant about math progs other than MMA - do you think the PARI, etc,. progs could be adapted to MMA effectively / efficiently?

Comment: am away for a couple of days, so will test when I get back & most likely accept then :)