# Generating a very large list of integers not divisible by a set of primes

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, prime-numbers

I have read [(58520)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58520), but the solutions there do not work when using a large maximum value because they rely on `Range`. For example, `ByteCount[Range[10^9]]` yields `8000000144`(8GB). Plus, I would be repeating that operation several thousand times, so memory efficiency is necessary.

If the set of primes only consists of one prime, I could use the following:

```
f[max_, prime_] := Flatten[Range[Range[prime - 1], max, prime]]
```

This solution does not generate all numbers from `1` to `max`, thus saving some memory (though not much because the resulting list is only about `1 / prime` shorter than `Range[max]`).

I have created the following solution, but it has a problem:

```
f[max_, primes_List] := 
  Block[{y = Range[Min[max, Times @@ primes]]}, 
   Scan[(y[[# ;; ;; #]] = Nothing) &, primes]; 
   If[max > Times @@ primes, Flatten[Range[y, max, Times @@ primes]], 
    y]];
```

The problem is that it may attempt to generate `Range[max]`, which is undesirable.

What are some memory efficient ways to create a list of integers that are not divisible by a set of primes?

Comment: Please give me a practical example where `fnHybrid` fails.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `f[10^10, Prime[Range[30]]` fails. The output should be a list of length `1147700420`.

Comment: `fnHybrid[1*^9, 30]` (my function, not yours) returns a list of 114,768,524 numbers in about 15 seconds on my system, but it does take about 12GB RAM.  I'll see if I can reduce that.

Comment: I think it should be possible to do this memory efficiently in blocks but I can't seem to think clearly about it at the moment and I need to get some other things done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a block-based modification of the first method in my answer to the earlier question:

```
fnBlock[x1_, x2_, primes_List] := 
   Fold[
     # ~Complement~ Range[x1 + #2 - Mod[x1, #2, 1], x2, #2] &,
     Range[x1, x2],
     primes
   ]

fnMem[x_Integer, n_Integer, block_: 1*^6] :=
  With[{pr = Prime @ Range @ n}, 
    Join @@ Table[
      fnBlock[1 + i block, Min[x, (i + 1) block], pr],
      {i, 0, ⌊x/block⌋}]
  ] ~Monitor~ i
```

Test with the default block length of one million:

```
fnMem[1*^9, 30] // Length // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]

{60.0292, 114768524}

1883324160
```

So this was four times slower than Simon's method but took about one sixth the RAM.

A block-based version of Simon's sieve would presumably be faster in this case (small *n*) but I do not feel like coding that as well right now.

---

It appears that in many cases my use of `Fold` in `fnBlock` is counterproductive; it is far slower and doesn't save much memory until *n* is large, where it is very slow indeed.  Here is a simpler alternative:

```
fnBlock2[x1_, x2_, p_List] :=
  Complement[
    Range[x1, x2],
    Join @@ Range[x1 + p - Mod[x1, p, 1], x2, p]
  ]
```

As an example here is a performance sample of the original `fnBlock`:

```
fnMem[1*^7, 7730] // Length // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {37.0502, 656850}
>
> 87750368
> ```

And again using the new `fnBlock2` (starting as always with a fresh kernel):

```
(* using fnBlock2 in place of fnBlock *)

fnMem[1*^7 , 7730] // Length // Timing
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> {1.31041, 656850}
>
> 124032312
> ```

So here it does use ~ 41% more memory but it is also 28 times faster.